# Azure AD B2C - Claim not being retained in session when step is directly navigated to

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are making use of custom policies in Azure AD B2C to define a combined sign in and registration user journey. The sign in orchestration steps appear earlier in the journey, and the registration orchestration steps appear towards the end.

Before we display the registration page, we have introduced a REST call to get some configuration (stored in a claim), but we only want this REST call to be made once per session - to do this we have added a `ClaimsExist` pre-condition to a new orchestration step which calls the REST technical profile, meaning the REST call should only be made if the claim does not already exist:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="XX" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>myConfigurationValue</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGetRegistrationConfigurationValue" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-GetRegistrationConfigurationValue" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Note the `myConfigurationValue` claim is set as an output claim in the `REST-GetRegistrationConfigurationValue` technical profile, so should be set and available in the claims bag after the technical profile has been called for the first time.

If the user begins to sign in (hitting earlier orchestration steps in the user journey) and then navigates to the registration step, they will hit the above orchestration step before seeing the registration page. If the user then hits the browser refresh button and again navigates to this orchestration step, the claim has been retained in the session meaning we do not make a second REST call - success! This is the behavior we expect.

However, if the user navigates directly to the above orchestration step by passing a query string parameter which skips all previous orchestration steps, the claim is not retained in the session and the REST call is made every single time the user refreshes the page. We want to avoid this.

Why does the behavior change if the above orchestration step is navigated to directly? The claim is output to the claims bag by the `REST-GetRegistrationConfigurationValue` technical profile, and so this claim should be retained in the session, so the next time the orchestration step is reached in the same session (e.g. by refreshing the page) the REST endpoint should not be called again due to the precondition - but this is not the case.

All help and ideas appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue might be that the precondition is evaluated before the claim is loaded from session. Would it work without the precondition if you have the session management profile set on the technical profile?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately setting the session management on the REST call doesn't make a difference - also if we add steps before the orchestration step with session management enabled it also doesn't work.

When you suggest removing the precondition, how could I then ensure that the REST call isn't made when the page is refreshed?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the REST profile would get skipped by the session data being there. For example self-asserted profiles can be skipped by having at least one of the output claims available in the configured session profile. Shame if it doesn't work for REST profiles :\